# ElasticSearch, size parameter doesn't work for helpers.scan function

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I use following python code to fetch the ElasticSearch record. I just want to get 50000 records. but the truth is that I get the whole index(more than 1 million records).

```
result = helpers.scan(
    es, 
    query={
        "_source": ["points.style_attrs.POI_TYPE", "point.poi_id.encrypted_value"],
        "size": 50000,
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {"term": {"metadata.tag": tag}},
                    {"term": {"metadata.city": city}}
                ]   
            }   
        }   
    },  
    size=1000,
    index=from_index)
```

When I debug the code, I just want to fetch some records to make sure my code is correct. If I fetch the whole index, I can't debug code quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing everything right, except the one thing you're doing with size. As quoted in the documentation of helpers.scan

> size: size (per shard) of the batch send at each iteration.

The helpers.scan method is supposed to return a generator which can be iterated through to fetch the records. In your case the code would look something like this:

```
result = helpers.scan(
es, 
query= your_query,
index=from_index)

count = 0
final_result = list()
for each_result in result:
    final_result.append(each_result)
    count += 1
    if count == 50000:
        break
```

Comment: So the network data transfer occurs at line "for each_result in result", not the line "result=helpers.scan()" , right?

Comment: That is true and its the beauty of generators. It'll be called only when you need it.

Comment: Would appreciate you accepting the answer if it helped ;)